# How to view static class members without an instance in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, static

I have an abstract class like this:

```
    private abstract class TBase : TRoot
    {
        internal static int c = 123;
    }
```

I'd like to see `c` value whenever I stop execution of the program (console app). If I put `TBase` into **Watch** window I get

> error CS0119: 'TBase' is a type, which is not valid in the given
>   context

Is there a way to monitor `TBase.c` without having an instance of `TBase` in VS 2015 debugger?

**Update:**
Oh, it's just intellisense not showing `c` in the drop-down

**Update2:**
What expression do I use in case of

```
private abstract class TBase<T, R> : TRoot
```

`TBase<,>.c` doesn't seem to work. Is it possible not to specify generic arguments?

Comment: Yeah, put `TBase.c` instead of just `TBase`.

Comment: If it's generic we have to specify it, ie, add TBase<int,string>.c in the watch window, for common abstract class, the TBase.c in the watch window will be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The watch window accepts any valid C# expression.

You can use `TBase.c`